# what is initial steps to run project which was already developed code. how to do for first time

Tags: python, django

i have old code which is on live , my manager gave code in zip file.

which is developed python 2.7 and Django 1.11
i downloaded and created environment.

when i started install requirement.txt file errors were come.

ERROR: No matching distribution found for alabaster==0.7.10
: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. Thi
s prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve

Comment: Hi the error is telling you that you may have to upgrade your python. I'm no python expert but I think old versions of python lose some of the libraries from repositories. So probably you'll have to locate the use of the affected libraries and upgrade then or even substitute them from other libraries.

Comment: But i have to work with python 2.7 only

Comment: But i have to work with python 2.7 only

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. You have several options here: Upgrade the library version (aka alabaster) and pray it will work; Find the library on some archive and use it from files instead; ... I don't have the ability to guide you more than that.